# VS Code: How to auto refresh Pylint

Tags: python, coding-style, visual-studio-code, pylint

I want the Pylint style suggestions to automatically update in VS code. E.g. if there is a style error, and I fix it I want it to automatically update, so I know if it is fixed.

Right now I have to save the file, wait a bit, and then see if it fixed the issue.

---

I am using `python 2.7` (via Anaconda) `pylint (1.6.4)`, and in VS Code I have `Python 0.5.8` and `Python for VSCode 0.2.3`

Answer (score 0):

You could turn auto save on.
See also this thread on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/8ab5hi/does_python_linting_only_run_upon_save/